# GitLab Runner error: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to setup a GitLab CI/CD pipeline using GitLab Runner and need to be able to use my host network with the containers instead of the default bridge network. Because of this, I added "network_mode = "host" to my GitLab Runner's config.toml file.

I have setup a docker-compose.yml file for my project which runs fine on my local pc. However, the build always fails with this error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.6.1
  on DevOpsCourseRunner AcswPCaLi
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:03
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:latest ...
Pulling docker image ubuntu:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:e4c58958181a5925816faa528ce959e487632f4cfd192f8132f71b32df2744b4 for ubuntu:latest with digest ubuntu@sha256:2b7412e6465c3c7fc5bb21d3e6f1917c167358449fecac8176c6e496e5c1f05f ...
Preparing environment
00:00
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: Error response from daemon: network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks (exec.go:78:0s). Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file (I use docker run hello-world for testing if the pipeline works and to ensure the issue is not with my docker-compose.yml file):

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

before_script:
  - docker-compose --version
  - docker --version

build_job:
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  tags:
    - build
    - docker
  script:
    - echo "Building the application..."
    - docker run --network host hello-world
  only:
    - project
```

My local pc os is Windows 11 and the GitLab Runner is Linux.

Any idea how I could fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be because you are using `services: docker:dind`.

This tries to create a link between the runner container and the service container. And links are not supported in `network_mode=host`.

Comment: I think it was because I used Docker for Windows, network_mode="host" is only available on Linux docker